# Regex for Replacing everything after instance of a character

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, notepad++

I have a large quantity of data in the following format:-

```
EXPERTISE_JOBTITLECOOKIE = "JobTitleCookie";
EXPERTISE_POSITIONCOOKIE = "PositionCookie";
EXPERTISE_QUALIFICATIONSPROFESSIONALMEMBERSHIPSCOOKIE = "QualificationsProfessionalMembershipsCookie";
EXPERTISE_YEARSOFEXPERIENCECOOKIE = "YearsOfExperienceCookie";
EXPERTISE_ADDITIONALCOMMENTSCOOKIE = "AdditionalCommentsCookie";
```

I'm looking for some regex that could be used to replace all characters after the `=` characters, to leave only the variable name in capitals.

I tried:

```
^\*\d+$
```

but this isn't picked up. I'm also looking for regex for the same problem that works in Sublime Text 2.

Could someone explain what the above does, and what I might be looking for in a RegEx statement?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of desired out for one or two line from above.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/mG9lK9/1)? ;).

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/qG3sH7/1)?

Comment: @nash_ag - I'd be left with EXPERTISE_JOBTITLECOOKIE on one line, followed by EXPERTISE_POSITIONCOOKIE on the next line and so on. Those are the only bits of the line that would remain.

Comment: @shA.t - Brill, many thanks! Just what I needed.

Comment: @John Crozier - Perfect thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

> Could someone explain what the `^\*\d+$` does

- `^` - Anchor that indicates the start of the line
- `\*` - The `*` character literally (since it's escaped)
- `\d+` - One or more digits `[0-9]`
- `$` - Anchor that indicates the end of the line

In other words, `^\*\d+$` will match a line such as `*1` or `*10000`.

---

You are looking for a regular expression to capture the characters *until* the `=` character:

```
^(.*?) =.*$
```

This will capture the characters before a space followed by the `=` character, and the match all of the remaining characters on that line so that they can be replaced.

If you want to remove everything after the capturing group, just replace with `\1` as demonstrated by this [example here](https://regex101.com/r/mB9cR4/1).

If you want to modify the string *after* the `=` character, replace with `\1 = "Some String"`, as demonstrated by this [example here](https://regex101.com/r/xO2tJ0/1).

Answer (score 6):

I'd do:

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `=.+$`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

Type <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Be sure you have checked `Regular Expression` but NOT `. matches newline`.

This will replace everything after `=` (included) by nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to replace the value of your variables to something. Question might be to what?

However, this regexp replaces your variable names to "aaa", whether you want it or not :)

Notepad++:

regexp:`([^=\r\n]*)=([^=\r\n]*)` 
replace with:`\1="aaa"`

regex explanation:
Read text not containing equal sign, then find a equal sign, then find text not containing equal sign, all on same line. group before = and after = in two different groups.
Refer to group 1, variable name (before =) when creating replace.

Comment: Sorry did not realize that not using code quotes could leave characters left out, which is NOT good when it comes to coding.. :)